# I broke Stackoverflow: HTML comments not editable. (sorry)

Tags: support, mathjax, comment

**Edit** this post describes a situation where I was unable to view the HTML artifact allowing me to edit or delete a comment in Chrome.

First an apology, on [breaking this question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/535590/4420)  I'm unable to edit my comment and the HTML link doesn't appear in the main site.

The comment I was trying to write was

```
w.r.t. "order of operations" in your final sample you have 
9\times 3\equiv 27 \equiv 7\pmod{10}$ 

why is it not written as  
9\pmod{10}$$ \times 3 \pmod{10}$$  \equiv 27\pmod{10}$$  \equiv 7\pmod{10}$$   
... in other words, when looking at one half of a congruence,
it's not immediately clear if \pmod{10}$$ has been applied or not.
```

I broke the internetz by deleting one of the "$" signs where the parsing seemed to make my plain text "mathified".

I'm new at se.Math and I'm new to this markup.  Sorry about the bug I created/discovered!

Comment: Isn't this the same problem as [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2652/comments-layout-break-if-math-expression-is-too-long)? If you can see cross which allows you do delete comment; then the solution is to delete it. If not you could perhaps try the workaround from that post, or flag for moderators attention and - hopefully - one of the moderators will delete the comment for you.

Comment: I've tried to fix it.  Tell me if it looks correct.

Comment: Also, in the future you can "test" your comments by typing them up as answers and checking the preview (and then copy-and-pasting it as a comment).  If you run into this problem again flag either the comment (if possible) or the post to which it is a comment for moderator attention.

Comment: @ArthurFischer Looks good, can you show me the code so I can learn from it?

Comment: Comments are not edible.

Comment: @makerofthings7: here's the code `w.r.t. "order of operations" in your final sample you have $9\times 3\equiv 27 \equiv 7\pmod{10}$ why is it not written as $9\pmod{10} \times 3 \pmod{10}  \equiv 27\pmod{10}  \equiv 7\pmod{10}$ ... in other words, when looking at one half of a congruence it's not immediately clear if $\pmod{10}$ has been applied or not.`

Comment: If you follow @ArthurFischer's suggestion to preview whatever you expect to be editing, as an answer, there is a "sandbox" thread for that purpose in meta. http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4666/sandbox-for-drafts-of-long-complex-answers  .  If you do it under a question there are some side effects in the case of accidentally clicking Submit Answer, such as bumping the question and leaving a deleted answer visible to users with higher 'reputation' (awful word for it, sorry).

Comment: @Asaf: You might eat your words.

Comment: @Jonas: No thank you, I already had dinner.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the comment not being editable: Comments can only be edited for 5 minutes after being posted.  After that time a comment cannot be changed, though you can always delete it and post a corrected version.

Comment: also regarding this... I was unable to click on the edit or delete link because the HTML was rendered in a location I couldn't reach (due to rendering)

Comment: @makerofthings7: Oh, I see.  Maybe you should edit your question to clarify this.